# How to remove ID from URL in Joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla2.5

I am trying to remove id from url in Joomla2.5.8.
so I tried to set a reference to the below URL.

http://developernote.com/2012/05/how-to-remove-id-from-url-in-joomla-2-5/

I succeeded to remove id like below.

joomla/index.php/aaaa/bbbb.html　≫　joomla/index.php/aaaa/bbbb/105-cccc.html

But Only displays a ”blank page”.
I don't know what was wrong.

Could you give me some advice?

-program development environment-
・joomla!2.5.8

・SEO　setting
Search Engine Friendly URL Yes
use URL　rewriting          No
Adds Suffix to URL         Yes（add .html)
UNICODE　Aliases            No

・htaccess 
no setting

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that most likely the article you are trying to link to does not have a corresponding menu item associated with it. The problem comes from itemID inheritance. When you don't have a specific menu item for an article, it then inherits the itemID from its parent category. By commenting out the lines in router.php, you are stopping this from happening so the article will not have an itemID and cause a 404 error. You either need to create a menu item directly to the item (which would eliminated the itemID to begin with) or you need to create a menu item for the parent category. In either case, you can put it in a new menu that is not displayed in any modules.